# I want the bottom container to coexist with the image and text in the center with flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make a cell like the image below.
[image: sample]

You can do it with just the container or just the image in the center, but it's difficult for me to establish both.

Below is the code I tried

```
Container(
        width: wi/3 - 10,
        height: wi/3 - 10,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: isSelected ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.darkBlack : Theme.of(context).colorScheme.lightBlack,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          image: const DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
            image: NetworkImage("https://www.gamba-osaka.net/c/faq/images/default.jpg"),
          )
        ),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Container(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints.tightFor(
              width: double.infinity,
            ),
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
              ),
            ),
            child: const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: Text("Following",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Thank you for reading this far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
         ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            child: Container(
              width: wi / 3 - 10,
              height: wi / 3 - 10,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black54,
              ),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Image.network(
                          "https://www.gamba-osaka.net/c/faq/images/default.jpg"),
                      const Text(
                        "Text",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 15),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    child: Container(
                      width: wi / 3 - 10,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.yellowAccent),
                      child: const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Following",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
```